how to preserve request body and make it accessible throughout the event handling process in nextjs
I was trying to update the database when each event is trigged.However trying to access the request body in each event fails,can anyone help me in preserve the request body  throughout the event handling process
  const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!);
   export async function POST(request: NextRequest, response: NextResponse) {
  const endpointSecret = process.env.NEXT_WEBHOOK_ENDPOINT_SECRET;
  let data;
  let eventType;
  let reponseData;
   if (endpointSecret) {
    let event;
    
    const payload =  await request.text();
    const sig = request.headers.get("stripe-signature");
    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig!, endpointSecret);
      eventType = event.type;
      data = event.data.object;
  switch (event.type) {
        case 'customer.subscription.created':
        updateAPI(event.data.object,request.body);
         break;
       case 'customer.subscription.deleted':
        updateAPI(event.data.object,request.body);
        break;
}
}
}


What type of error to be specific? Signature error? Need more information.

I was sending payment_id in request, when an event is triggred by stripe  the request got errased  so i was not able to update the database using payment_id

How did you set the payment_id in the request? The event body will only contain the fields of object specification. For example, customer.subscription.* event will only contain fields for Subscription object.
